# Array 1 and array 2 are reverse-sorted arrays. I write a program that merges these arrays to a new reverse-sorted array

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, x86

Array 1 and array 2 are reverse-sorted arrays.
I write a program that merges these arrays to a new reverse-sorted array.

```
.global _start
.section .data
 array1: .int 6,4,0
 array2: .int 5,3,0
 mergedArray: .zero 20
.section .text
_start:
    # set up the input array pointers
    leal array1, %eax   # pointer to the first element of array1
    leal array2, %ebx   # pointer to the first element of array2
    # set up the output array pointer
    leal mergedArray, %ecx   # pointer to the first element of output_array
    # set up the loop counters
    movl $0, %edx    # counter for array1
    movl $0, %esi    # counter for array2

loop:
    # compare the current elements of the two arrays
    movl (%eax,%edx,4), %edi   # load the current element of array1 into %edi
    movl (%ebx,%esi,4), %ebp   # load the current element of array2 into %ebp
    cmpl %edi, %ebp            # compare the two elements
    jg elementArray1Greater    # if the element from array1 is greater than the element from array1, add it to the output array
    jl elementArray2Greater    # if the element from array2 is greater than the element from array2, add it to the output array
    jmp equal   

elementArray1Greater:
     movl %edi, (%ecx,%edx,4)   # add the current element of array1 to the output array
     leal 4(%ecx), %ecx
     addl $4, %edx              # advance the counter for array1
     jmp loop

elementArray2Greater:
     movl %ebp, (%ecx,%esi,4)   # add the current element of array2 to the output array
     leal 4(%ecx), %ecx
     addl $4, %esi              # advance the counter for array2
     jmp loop

equal:  cmpl $0, %edi
        je finish
        movl %edi, (%ecx,%edx,4)   # add the current element of array1 to the output array
        leal 4(%ecx), %ecx
        addl $4, %edx
        addl $4, %esi
        jmp loop 

finish:     movl %ebp, (%ecx,%esi,4)   # add the current element of array2 to the output array
    # exit
    movl $0, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

I get SF error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004000df in elementArray1Greater ()
```

I used objdump command and get (the SF line is the yellow line):

[image]

Information of the registers :
[image]

I consider the problem is the `leal 4(%ecx), %ecx` command but when I got rid of it , there is still a SF error.

I can't figure out the problem and appreciate any help.

Comment: That register dump doesn't look like it's from the point where you crashed, since GDB is saying you hit a breakpoint not the segfault, and EDX is still 0.  (Although ECX has advanced from the initial address, but not out of the same page.)  It's weird that you scale EDX by 4 in the addressing mode, but *also* increment it by 4.  But you're doing one dword at a time, 4 bytes not an XMM vector of 16 bytes.

Comment: Also, it looks like you built your code as 64-bit, but it happens to work because all the addresses are in the low 32 bits of address-space so truncating them to 32-bit doesn't produce invalid addresses.  But if you ever used ESP to access the stack you'd have a problem.  Use `gcc -m32 -nostdlib -static foo.S`.

Comment: Also, your `jmp loop` instructions in your source are in comments on the previous line, not matching your disassembly.  BTW, copy/paste text as text in code blocks, not pictures of text disassembly or GDB output.  And see also the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for GDB asm tips, like `layout reg` / `layout next` to show regs as you single-step.

Answer (score 0):

> I consider the problem is the `leal 4(%ecx), %ecx` command [*sic*] but when I got rid of it , there is still a SF error.

It is not so much *that* particular instruction but the fact that you combine it with the scaled index addressing mode makes you take giant steps walking through the *mergedArray* and hence touching memory that does not belong to the array.

### The source arrays

If you are going to traverse the source arrays using a scaled index addressing mode, then you need to adjust the associated index register %EDX / %EBP with a simple increment of 1. Adding 4 to the index register in combination with the multiplication by 4 will make you address memory outside of these arrays. The simpler solution of course is to refrain from using the scaled index addressing mode and just add 4 to the pointer register %EAX / %EBX.

### The destination array

You are traversing the destination array using a scaled index addressing mode for which you use a couple of index registers %EDX / %EBP that bear no relation whatsoever to the destination array! Also, since you already add 4 to the pointer register %ECX, there's no need to use the scaled index addressing mode at all.

### Amended algorithm

```
  leal  array1, %eax        # pointer to array1
  leal  array2, %ebx        # pointer to array2
  leal  mergedArray, %ecx   # pointer to mergedArray

loop:
  movl  (%eax), %edi        # load current element array1 into %edi
  movl  (%ebx), %ebp        # load current element array2 into %ebp
  cmpl  %edi, %ebp          # compare the two elements
  jg    elementArray1Greater
  jl    elementArray2Greater

equal:
  testl %edi, %edi
  jz    finish
  leal  4(%ebx), %ebx       # Advance in array2
  ---- fall through for smaller footprint (less code) ----
elementArray1Greater:
  movl  %edi, (%ecx)        # add element of array1 to output array
  leal  4(%eax), %eax       # Advance in array1
  leal  4(%ecx), %ecx       # Advance in mergedArray
  jmp   loop

elementArray2Greater:
  movl  %ebp, (%ecx)        # add element of array2 to output array
  leal  4(%ebx), %ebx       # Advance in array2
  leal  4(%ecx), %ecx       # Advance in mergedArray
  jmp   loop

finish:
  movl  %edi, (%ecx)        # Add 0 to mergedArray
```

### Test this too

> ```
> array1: .int 6,4,0
> array2: .int 5,3,0
> ```

Make sure you also check for the case where both arrays hold a same number that is not the terminating zero:

```
array1: .int 6,3,0
array2: .int 5,3,0
```